# How to create springboot Aggregation from my mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have developed some part of code
My pipeline seems like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    $sort: { fraccion: 1, fec_fin: 1 },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$fraccion",
      fec_fin: { $last: "$fec_fin" },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "cat_nico",
      let: { tigie_fraccion: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$d_fraccion",
                    "$$tigie_fraccion",
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$d_nico",
            f_fin_vig: { $last: "$f_fin_vig" },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            d_nico: "$_id",
            f_fin_vig: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "nico",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      fraccion: "$_id",
      fec_fin: 1,
      nico: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [{ $size: "$nico" }, 0] },
          [
            {
              d_nico: "00",
              f_fin_vig: "$fec_fin",
            },
          ],
          "$nico",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$nico",
  },
  {
    $set: {
      nico: "$nico.d_nico",
      f_fin_vig: "$nico.f_fin_vig",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      fraccion: fraccion, 
      nico: nico,
    },
  },
])
```

Mi problem when I run mi server and I got the next error:

Forwarding to error page from request due to exception [Invalid reference 'd_nico'!]

I have tried using addfields to create my set and directly a project but I not very Pro to solve this.
Anyone have any Ideas?

```
String fraccion = f.getFraccion().substring(0, 8);
                    String nico = f.getFraccion().substring(8); 
                    
                    SortOperation sortOperation = sort(Direction.ASC, "fraccion", "fec_fin");
                    
                    GroupOperation group = group("fraccion").last("fec_fin").as("fec_fin");

                    Map<String, Document> letOperationParameters = new HashMap<>();
                    letOperationParameters.put("tigie_fraccion", new Document("$toString", "$_id"));
                    
                    List<AggregationOperation> pipeline1 = Arrays.asList(
                            match(Criteria.where("$expr").is(new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$d_fraccion", "$$tigie_fraccion")))),
                            group("d_nico").last("f_fin_vig").as("f_fin_vig"),
                            project().and("_id").as("d_nico").andInclude("f_fin_vig")
                            );
                    LookupPipelineOperation lookupOperation1 = new LookupPipelineOperation(
                            "cat_nico",
                            letOperationParameters,
                            pipeline1,
                            "nico"
                            );
                    
                    ProjectionOperation projection1 = project()
                            .andExclude("_id")
                            .and("_id").as("fraccion")
                            .and("fec_fin").as("fec_fin")
                            .and(ConditionalOperators.Cond.when(Criteria.where("$nico").size(0))
                                    .then(Arrays.asList(
                                                    new Document("d_nico", "00"),
                                                    new Document("f_fin_vig", "$fec_fin")
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    .otherwise("$nico")
                                    ).as("nico");

                    UnwindOperation unwind = unwind("nico");
                    
                    //El error radica en que d_nico no esta definido hasta este contexto y hay que renombrarlo para usarlo en las operaciones posteriores
                    Fields setOperation = bind("nico", "$nico.d_nico").and("f_fin_vig", "$nico.f_fin_vig");
                    
                    
                    
                    MatchOperation match = match(Criteria.where("fraccion").is(fraccion).and("nico").is(nico));
                                        
                    List<AggregationOperation> aggregationFilter = new ArrayList<>();
                    aggregationFilter.add(sortOperation);
                    aggregationFilter.add(group);
                    aggregationFilter.add(lookupOperation1);
                    aggregationFilter.add(projection1);
                    aggregationFilter.add(unwind);
                    aggregationFilter.add(setOperation);
                    aggregationFilter.add(match);
                    
                    CatTigie unique_fracc = cattigierepository.firstByAggregation(CatTigie.class, aggregationFilter);
```